# lodash: and_then-like behavior for chain

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash

Is there any way in lodash that works like `chain`, but pass value to next stage only when it is not `undefined`? Just behaves as `Result<T>::and_then` in Rust?

For example:

```
_.chain_another({a: '123'})
  .get('a.b') // returns undefined
  .toNumber() // no error, returns undefined
  .value() // undefined
```

Comment: There was a [discussion](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/527) about adding a maybe monad to lodash, but AFAIK there's nothing yet.

Comment: Most if not all lodash functions are null-safe, though. Your example wouldn't throw an error, it would return `NaN`.

Comment: You can achieve something similar if you lift the value to an array and then map over it. `_.chain({ a: '123' }).get('a.b').castArray().compact().map(_.toNumber).head().value()`. Returns `undefined` and `_.toNumber` is never called.